# How do you know if a bond according to VB theory consists of 2 "3 electron bonds" or one "fully paired" bond?

Tags: physical-chemistry, bond, theoretical-chemistry, valence-bond-theory

First of all, I want to discuss the whole thing strictly according to the VB - theory and not use any concepts of the MO - theory.

According to Linus Pauling, the "3 electron Bond" is the resonance of one electron between 2 half filled orbitals:

A| •B <-> A• |B

I use his representation: "A•••B".

I applied that Idea to Triplett Oxygen, which has one sigma bond and 2 x ½ π Bonds or "2 x 3 electron bonds": "O÷÷÷O" so it forms one sigma Bond between the two half filled 2py orbitals and two ½ π Bonds between

1. one fully occupied 2px orbital and one half filled 2pz orbital.
2. one half filled 2pz orbital and one fully occupied 2px orbital

[image]

Then I moved on to Peroxid with O2--.

I now have two options:

1. Starting with the following electron configuration: O: 2s² 2px² 2py¹ 2pz¹, O--: 2s² 2px² 2py² 2pz²

That must lead to two "3 electron bonds": "O:::O".

2. Starting with the following electron configuration: O-: 2s² 2px² 2py² 2pz¹, O-: 2s² 2px² 2py² 2pz¹

That must lead to one sigma bond: "O-O".

I know that it can't be option one because Peroxide is diamagnetic and probably more energetically favourable to form a single sigma bond than two ½ π Bonds, but is there another explanation for that?

I also tried to apply that on Dioxygenyl, and endet up with one sigma bond, one π bond and one ½ π Bond: "O=•••O":

[image]

But then I didn't have to face this question because I could only start with O and O+ or O+ and O.

Comment: I don't know why somebody downvoted without giving a reason, so I can't improve my question...

Answer (score 1):

You can't, really.

Trihalide ions, $\ce{X3^-}$, are known for all halogens with stable isotopes ($\ce{F,Cl,Br,I}$). Conventionally they are regarded as having a two-elecron bond delocalized between two linkages, to wit:

$\ce{X-X\space\space :X^-\space\space <->\space\space X:^-\space\space X-X}$

But this apparently applies only for $\ce{Cl, Br, I}$. [Braida and Hubertus[1]](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja046443a) report that trifluoride ion, with the same formal valence structure as the others, has a stronger contribution from a delocalized three-electron bonding:

$\ce{F\therefore F^-\space\space \cdot F\space\space <->\space\space F\cdot\space\space F\therefore F^-}$

with the negative charge more delocalized here than in the "standard" structure that seems to apply to the heavier trihalide ions.

Both structures correspond to the same valence-bond arrangementcand thus simple valence bond theory cannot distinguish them. It's one area where molecular orbital theory is superior.

**Reference**

1. Benoit Braida and Phillipe C. Hubertus(2004). "What makes the F3- ion so special?" A breathing-orbital valence-bond ab initio study. _Journal of the American Chemical Society, 126(45), 14890-14898. https://doi.org/10.1021/ja046443a.

Comment: Oh ok thank you! I have to give a poster presentation on the binding in O2+, O2, O2-, O2-- in the 1st semester and thought it would be best to illuminate all of them once purely from the VB theory and then from the MO theory, at least then I have discussion material when I try to present it this way ;)

Comment: But can't VB theory predict bond strength or bond lenght somehow? I've read that a π bond is slightly weaker than a sigma bond, so shouldn't it be possible to calculate if it's rather a single sigma bond or two ½ π bonds somehow?

Comment: (I'm far from any calculations in quantum mechanics, that's more a superficial question)